# Что почитать про тонкости многопоточности и параллелизма?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, .net

Саму многопоточность уже освоил. Но хотелось бы углубить свои знания по качественным изданиям.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мой коллега написал: [Multithreading in C#5.0. Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/multithreading-c-50-cookbook)

Answer (score 3):

Я бы посоветовал классику - Джеффри Рихтера. В его замечательной CLR via C# довольно большой раздел (часть 5) посвящён многопоточности. Это несколько глав о потоках, о пуле потоков, об асинхронной модели, где все достаточно тщательно и подробно расписано. Плюс, если говорить о статье, которую посоветовал [@VladD](/users/10105/vladd) то она, по-моему, есть в русском переводе на rsdn. Но

Comment: ... но не в очень хорошем переводе и не последняя версия текста

Comment: Если человек не дружит с английским, то не очень новый и не очень хороший перевод все же лучше никакого. Если же дружит, то, конечно, перевод не нужен

Answer (score 2):

Ну вот например: http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Answer (score 1):

Поддерживаю все указанные книги и еще могу посоветовать [Concurrency in C# Cookbook](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1449367569/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=1449367569&linkCode=as2&tag=stepheclearys-20&linkId=VZYFOOYTQN57RD5L).

Ну и практика-практика-практика и набивание шишек. На hello world многому не научишься, к сожалению.

Answer (score 1):

[The Art of Multiprocessor Programming](http://www.amazon.com/The-Multiprocessor-Programming-Revised-Reprint/dp/0123973376)